# Typehint module (namespace)

Tags: typescript

I'm importing a module and I want to typehint it in a function but I'm getting

> Cannot use namespace 'joi' as type

```
import joi from "joi";

export function init(cb: (joi: joi) => any) {
  let result = cb(joi);
  ...
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`joi` is a value (at runtime it will be an object that contains the exports of the module) you want a type that has the structure of the `joi` value. You can do this using `typeof`:

```
import * as joi from "joi";

export function init(cb: (_joi: typeof joi) => any) {
    let result = cb(joi);
}
```

**Note** I renamed the parameter to `_joi` because otherwise `typeof` would have tried to retrieve the type of the parameter not the import because of scoping rules.

Comment: Pfft I was so close, I tried `joi: typeof joi` but it appears that it was being confused because the name was the same. I changed the import to `Joi` and `joi: typeof Joi` works now. Thank you!